# Undefined Method `stringify_keys' for Model's Show Page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In trying to access the show view for one of my models `workouts#show` I have been getting an error that says:

```
undefined method `stringify_keys' for "/workouts/abs-0002":String
```

It's calling it on a link in a `_template.html.erb`, which is being rendered in my `workouts#show` page (error called on the first line):

```
  <%= link_to "Do this one!", workout_path(workout) do %>
    <p class="cta">Pick me!</p>
  <% end %>
```

My `workouts` controller is:

```
class WorkoutsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @workouts = Workout.all
  end

  def show
    @workout = Workout.friendly.find(params[:id])
    @exercise = Exercise.new
    @report = Report.new
  end

  def new
    @workout = Workout.new
    @workout.user_id = current_user
  end

  def create
    @workout = Workout.new(workout_params)
    @workout.user = current_user

    if @workout.save
      flash[:notice] = "Workout was saved successfully."
      redirect_to @workout
    else
      flash.now[:alert] = "Error creating workout. Please try again."
      render :new
    end
  end

  def edit
    @workout = Workout.friendly.find(params[:id])
    @workout.user_id = current_user
  end

  def update
    @workout = Workout.friendly.find(params[:id])

    @workout.name = params[:workout][:name]
    @workout.workout_type = params[:workout][:workout_type]
    @workout.teaser = params[:workout][:teaser]
    @workout.description = params[:workout][:description]
    @workout.video = params[:workout][:video]
    @workout.difficulty = params[:workout][:difficulty]
    @workout.trainer = params[:workout][:trainer]
    @workout.user_id = params[:workout][:user_id]

    if @workout.save
       flash[:notice] = "Workout was updated successfully."
      redirect_to @workout
    else
      flash.now[:alert] = "Error saving workout. Please try again."
      render :edit
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @workout = Workout.friendly.find(params[:id])

    if @workout.destroy
      flash[:notice] = "\"#{@workout.name}\" was deleted successfully."
      redirect_to action: :index
    else
      flash.now[:alert] = "There was an error deleting the workout."
      render :show
    end
  end

  private
  def workout_params
    params.require(:workout).permit(:name, :workout_type, :teaser, :description, :video, :difficulty, :trainer, :user_id)
  end
end
```

And my `workout.rb` model is:

```
class Workout < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :name, use: :slugged

  belongs_to :user
  has_many :exercises
  has_many :reports
  validates :user, presence: true
end
```

Can anyone help me see what's going wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

according to http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to, you need to remove the first param if you want to use a custom name for the link:

> You can use a block as well if your link target is hard to fit into the name parameter. ERB example:

```
<%= link_to(@profile) do %>
  <strong><%= @profile.name %></strong> -- <span>Check it out!</span>
<% end %>

# => 
<a href="/profiles/1">
  <strong>David</strong> -- <span>Check it out!</span>
</a>
```

Comment: Beautiful!  Thank you!